# Comparing multiple values within a dictionary and returning key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, comparison

I have a dictionary where the keys are an arbitrary name and the values are an mtime of a file. Example:

`{'server_1': 1506286408.854673, 'server_2': 1506286219.1254442, 'server_3':1506472359.154043}`

I wish to iterate over comparing two of the values from the dictionary finding the largest of the two, and returning the key of said large value and continuing to do this until there is only a single key:val pair left.

I know there is a way of "ordering" dictionaries by value with some tricks provided by outside libraries like operator and defaultdict. However, I was curious if there was an  easier way to accomplish this goal and avoid trying to sort a naturally unordered structure.

So the end result I would be looking for is the first iteration to return server_3, then server_1 and then  stop there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to sort dictionary based on values but ignore the last one.

```
def keys_sorted_by_values(d):
    return [ k for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True) ][:-1]

server_to_mtime = {'server_1': 1506286408.854673, 'server_2': 1506286219.1254442, 'server_3':1506472359.154043}    
for server in keys_sorted_by_values(server_to_mtime):
    print(server)
```

#### Output

```
server_3
server_1
```